# Sharepoint 2007 - search

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a sharepoint site.. in that i have uploaded some docs in the doc library... that includes .pptx file saved as web page i.e. '.mht' file... Those docs are not appearing in the search result.. I have checked the FileTypes in cental admin search settings..
In that .mht file type is included.. can anyone tell me what i have to do to make these docs to appear in tje search result...?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--search/mht-files-not-showing-up-in-search-36954.shtml). It has a proposed solution for mht files.

Comment: For me the normal .mht files are appearing in search.. but only the pptx files saved as web page with .mht externsion is not aappearing.. I have mht IFilter installed in the server... When i checked in the crawl log, for that doc there is a warning message saying 'Some parts of this document cannot be accessed'...